# Многоуровневая группировка строк в Excel силами Python

Tags: python, excel

Python 3.8.0
ОС: Windows 10
Используемые библиотеки: win32com.client

Добрый день.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать многоуровневую группировку в Excel силами Python.

Я нашел способ через Sheet.Rows(’10:20′).OutlineLevel=2, но здесь требуется указывать уровень группировки, что сильно усложняет код.

Способ через Sheet.Rows(’10:20′).Group=True работает, но после первого выполнения падает в ошибку и выполнение кода заканчивается.

> File «F:\Python38\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py», line
>   581, in **setattr** raise AttributeError(«Property ‘%s.%s’ can not be
>   set.» % (self.*username*, attr)) AttributeError: Property
>   ‘.Group’ can not be set.

Comment: pandas не подходит что ли?

Comment: Не представляю как ее использовать.  Под группировкой имеется в виду оформление строк в Excel, когда можно нажать "+/-" и раскрыть/скрыть строки